# How to setup Dynamic Data Dropdown control in Orbeon Forms CE?

Tags: orbeon

I am a newcomer in the Orbeon forms and I am trying to use Dynamic Data Dropdown component with Orbeon Forms CE but nothing is displayed.

As an example, I am trying to fetch data from the following web service: 
http://api.geonames.org/earthquakes?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo&style=full

In order to use the aforementioned web service, I entered the following values in the provided fields:

```
"Choices XPath expression": "/geonames/earthquake",
"Label XPath expression": "@src" ,
"Value XPath expression: "@eqid"
```

Unfortunately, the dropdown component is always empty. Is something wrong with the values at these fields? Although, there is available documentation about this component, I've noticed that there is a broken link regarding the sample web service that is used in this documentation.

Thank you

Comment: Currently, the service returns an error message saying that "the daily limit of 20000 credits for demo has been exceeded". Would you be able to quote a snippet of what is being returned by the service, so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply and sorry about the link. You can find the returned content of the service at the following address: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html (it is the number 7 in the provided list). I have also tried to use some other services from the same site but nothing is displayed! Actually, I am going to build my web service but I'd like first to use an existing one in order to check how to setup this kind of control in an orbeon form that will be able to consume data provided by a web service.

Comment: Hi George, I am still unable to see what the service returns, as the documentation links to an XML file that returns the same error. If you could save the XML you get on your side, paste it in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com), and link to it a comment, I can then try this on my side. ‑Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Your XML is like:

```
    <geonames>
       <earthquake>
          <src>us</src>
          <eqid>c0001xgp</eqid>
          <datetime>2011-03-11 04:46:23</datetime>
          <lat>38.322</lat>
          <lng>142.369</lng>
          <magnitude>8.8</magnitude>
          <depth>24.4</depth>
       </earthquake>
       ...
```

@src is used in case you hace a XML node like `<node src="something"/>` but in your case what you need is to access to text between tags.

Try with:

```
"Choices XPath expression": "/geonames/earthquake",
"Label XPath expression": "src/text()" ,
"Value XPath expression: "eqid/text()"
```

Hope it helps. Regards

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's now working properly.

Comment: @GeorgePapas Glad to help!